# Angular file upload to Laravel. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, laravel, file, http, cors

So I've been working on an Angular 5 - Laravel app, where Angular is the front end and Laravel is working as an API.

So far the project has been able to perform pretty much every CRUD operation, but until now I haven't uploaded any files yet, this is were this problem started to appear.

I got the following error as a response from laravel:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already have a CORS middleware in laravel set as follows:

```
return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept');
```

The logic at angular to upload the file is something like this:

Controller:

```
addActivity(): void {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', this.newActivity.name);
    formData.append('turnedInDate', (new Date(this.newActivity.turnedInDate)).toUTCString());
    formData.append('file', this.newActivity.file, this.newActivity.fileName);

    this.isLoadingModal = true;

    this.activitiesService.create(formData, this.studentSelected.id, true)
      .finally(() => this.isLoading = false)
      .subscribe(
        response => {},
        (error: AppError) =>{ throw error; }
      );
  }
```

Service:

```
create(data: any, parentId?: number, appendHeaders?: boolean): Observable<any> {
    let options = null;

    if(appendHeaders) {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }

    return this.http.post(this.url + this.parentEndpoint + (parentId || '') + this.endpoint + this.token, data, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This and any other header i put gives me the mentioned error, and with this in particular, "multipart/form-data" gives me the following error:

```
Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried sending no headers, an "Accept: application/json" header, but it seems that for this particular case, Laravel just doesn't care and returns the error as if no CORS middleware is present.

Comment: Client will first send an OPTIONS request, then if the cors headers are ok it'll send the actual POST, so without knowing much about Laravel, I'd guess you aren't checking the request method. If it's OPTIONS you should just return the headers and stop processing, that may be why the error 'missing boundary'. Also, I think some browsers don't allow * with POST as the allow-origin these days. You need to check the Origin -header from the options-request and set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the same value (or a hard-coded one, ie. full protocol+domain+port ).

Comment: Well the thing is that I have been able to do every request to Laravel so far, pretty much every CRUD operation with the configuration set above. However those requests didn't have any files, now that this one has a file I haven't been able to successfully receive the request to Laravel due to the "access-control-allow-origin" error. The boundary one was because of the multipart header that I set, but taking it off doesn't throw show that, so I'll omit it. The problem is with the other one though

Comment: try this on laravel https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: I already have a cors middleware in laravel as explained above

Comment: How do the headers compare between a regular post and an upload, in the network tab? Is Origin there? Btw I don't think you need to set content--type when data is FormData, if you're using HttpClient.

Comment: Well I made the little discovery. At laravel I was trying to print the $request variable, and apparently that generates the error because when I commented it it didn't appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in Laravel I wanted to print the $request variable to see if everything was received at the server correctly, something like:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id) {
    print_r($request);
    echo $id;
}
```

I just commented the print_r line and the error was gone. The id was echoed correctly, so I set a $file variable to $request->file('file); and everything works fine.

Not sure what does printing the $request has to do with throwing an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error though.